# TypeError: must be real number, not method

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, typeerror

I am following this guide on YouTube [Python + PyTorch + Pygame Reinforcement Learning – Train an AI to Play Snake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8ypSXwyBds) and getting the error below.

I have uploaded the code to GitHub : [Here](https://github.com/dhruvyadav89300/AI-SNAKE-GAME)

```
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.11.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dhruvyadav/Desktop/Projects/AI-Snake-Game/agent.py", line 142, in <module>
    train()
  File "/Users/dhruvyadav/Desktop/Projects/AI-Snake-Game/agent.py", line 120, in train
    agent.train_short_memory(state_old, final_move, reward, state_new, done)
  File "/Users/dhruvyadav/Desktop/Projects/AI-Snake-Game/agent.py", line 84, in train_short_memory
    self.trainer.train_step(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
  File "/Users/dhruvyadav/Desktop/Projects/AI-Snake-Game/model.py", line 34, in train_step
    next_state = torch.tensor(next_state, dtype=torch.float)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: must be real number, not method
```

Comment: Whatever next_state is the error is telling you that it must be a number

Comment: Yeah, I don't know where is it getting converted to a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `state_new = agent.get_state` to `state_new = agent.get_state()` in the following code extract ([link to github](https://github.com/dhruvyadav89300/AI-SNAKE-GAME/blob/235a425f67dc7a145e07f1bfa0dcab6788f58e9b/agent.py#L108C1-L118C1)).

```py
    while True:
        # Get old state
        state_old = agent.get_state(game)
        
        # Get move based on current state
        final_move = agent.get_action(state_old)

        # Perform the move and get the new state
        reward, done, score = game.play_step(final_move)
        state_new = agent.get_state()
```

Without the parenthesis, you give the method instead of the result of the method.